# Can't call WCF service contract with two or more parameters

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

This is my WCF contracts:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "{type}/sports")]
    List<SportsList> GetSportsList(string type);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "{type}/sports/{sport}/championships")]
    ChampsCountries GetChampsBySport(string type, string sport);
```

When I try to call it from my WPF application:

```
                Service1Client client = new Service1Client();
                SportsList[] sports = client.GetSportsList("line");
```

As you see I am calling the first contract, but it gives an Error regarding my second contract:

`Operation 'GetChampsBySport' of contract 'IService1' specifies multiple request body parameters to be serialized without any wrapper elements. At most one body parameter can be serialized without wrapper elements. Either remove the extra body parameters or set the BodyStyle property on the WebGetAttribute/WebInvokeAttribute to Wrapped`.

I already have changed `BodyStyle` to `Wrapped` and what else should I do?
I am able to call that contract from browser with no problem. Maybe something to do with my config? This is my WPF application config:

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:1001/Services/Service1.svc" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior"
    binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MainService.IService1" />
</client>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add WCF reference in your Visual Studio project, it doesn't fully support all WCF REST methods. I suggest to open your `Reference.cs` file and find yor 'GetChampsBySport' operation. Then add the following:

```
[WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
```

If you can't add `WebInvoke` then add a reference to `System.ServiceModel.Web` extension from References.